How to compute gradient of loss wrt many inputs in pytorch
I want to compute the gradient of a loss wrt a large neural network in pytorch. The loss is of form L = g(f(x1), f(x2), f(x3), ..., f(xn)), where there are potentially many xs, f is the neural network, and g is a relatively simple nonlinear function. A naive implementation is:
zs = []
for x in inputs:
    z = f(x)
    zs.append(z)
zs = torch.stack(zs)
L = g(zs)
L.backward()

But this will eat up VRAM, as there will be len(inputs) copies of computation graphs attached to L. I decide instead to compute through chain rule. Let dL be the gradient of the loss wrt f's parameters, and dzi be the Jacobian of zi wrt f's parameters. Then dL = dL/dz1 dz1 + dL/dz2 dz2 + ... + dL/dzn dzn. If we know dL/dzi beforehand, we may simply accumulate each dL/dzi dzi into the .grad of neural network parameters, without keeping more than one computation graph within VRAM. Here is the code:
zs = []
# Do not build computation graph.
with torch.no_grad():
    for x in inputs:
        z = f(x)  # NOTE #1
        zs.append(z)
# Compute dL/dz.
zs = torch.stack(zs).requires_grad_()
L = g(zs)
L.backward()
zs_grad = torch.empty_like(zs).copy_(zs.grad)
# Each computation graph will be freed at backward.
for x, dL_dz in zip(inputs, zs_grad):
    z = f(x)  # NOTE #2
    z.backward(gradient=dL_dz)

If f is pure function, this should work. However, in reality, f may contain batch normalization, dropout etc. that preserve some sort of inner state. As a matter of fact, in my use case, f will be a pre-trained model, and I can't change its component arbitrarily. I need to ensure that z at NOTE #1 is identical to z at NOTE #2 for each x, but randomness in dropout will ruin the identity. Even if randomness is somehow controlled, passing x twice through a batch norm will ruin the inner running average of the batch norm as well.
I thought implementing the gradient computation should be fairly easy, but then I got stuck. I asked the same question on pytorch forum. But it's not getting much attention, so I ask again here. Thank you so much for your help!

Why don't you pass inputs in batches and calculate the gradient for each batch? Even if you want to have a batch size of 1, you can calculate the gradient for each batch (x) just after passing through the model (f).

Hi @rajkumar_data, could you elaborate on it a bit? If I understand your idea correctly, you want to compute dL1 = dL/dz1 dz1, dL2 = dL/dz2 dz2, all the way  to dLn = dL/dzn dzn, and finally add all dLi to one dL. The problem is that g is nonlinear; thus, e.g. to compute dL/dz1, we will need all other zi = f(xi) as well. So at the end of the day, we are still computing each f(xi) at least twice, and have to face the inconsistency issue.

now I understand the role of g and how it makes everything complicated
